# HTML <textarea> not working with Grammarly - overlapping another div

Tags: html

Strange one. 
I've a very simple webpage for testing. Code below. 
I get the resulting issue with teh Grammarly G icons not in the textareas. This happens when you need to scroll up and down the screen. As soon as you scroll, they move out of the textareas and overlap a div below.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="report" style="border: red solid thin">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td style="border:thin black solid;">
        <textarea rows="10" cols="80">TESTING AN ISSUE. WILL BE BACK ONLINE SHORTLY1</textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border:thin black solid;">
        <textarea rows="10" cols="80">TESTING AN ISSUE. WILL BE BACK ONLINE SHORTLY2</textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border:thin black solid;">
        <textarea rows="10" cols="80">TESTING AN ISSUE. WILL BE BACK ONLINE SHORTLY3</textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border:thin black solid;">
        <textarea rows="10" cols="80">TESTING AN ISSUE. WILL BE BACK ONLINE SHORTLY4</textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="menu" style="text-align: center; border: thin blue solid; ">
Test<br/>
Test<br/>
Test<br/>
Test<br/>
Test<br/>
Test<br/>
Test<br/>
Test<br/>
Test<br/>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

The result when I scroll is this
[reult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOLr9.png)

Comment: When I set this at the top of the page it does.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>

Answer (score 0):

Setting out like this works...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```